# something is going wrong in submitting form data through ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to submit a form's data to database using ajax. I am unable to figure out what's going wrong.

The below part is the HTML containing the form data.

HTML->

```
<form id="myForm" method="post">
    NAME:<input type="text" id="name" name="name">
    PICKUP:<input type="text" id="pick" name="pick">
    DROP:<input type="text" id="drop" name="drop">

    <input type="submit" id="sub" value="Submit"></button>
  </form>
  <div class=".data"></div>
```

The below part inlcudes the ajax calls. I have included the jquery CDN.

JAVASCRIPT->

```
$("#myForm").submit( function(){
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var pick = $("#pick").val();
        var drop = $("#drop").val();
        var str = name+"/"+pick+"/"+drop;
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "p_inp.php",
          data: "str="+str,
          success: function(data){
            $(".data").html(data);
          }
        });

    });
    $("#myForm").submit( function(){
    return false;
  });
```

The following is the PHP file which enters the data into database.

PHP file->

```
    <?php

    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','pagal.com','next');

    //echo 'HI';
    $str = $_POST['str'];
    $s = explode("/",$str);
    $name = $s[0];
    $pick = $s[1];
    $drop = $s[2];


    $sql = "select count(*) as c from passenger";
    $res = $con->query($sql);
    while($row = $res->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $c = $row['c'];
    }
    $c = $c+1;
    //echo $c;
    $sql = "insert into passenger values('$c','$name','$pick','$drop')";
    if($con->query($sql))
        echo 'Data entered Successfully<br>';
    else echo 'Something Went Wrong<br>';

    $con->close();

?>
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: You need to add `event.preventDefault();` in your Submit function

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. I strongly advise you read this :  [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: @executable, can u show me a demo by editing the code ? thankyou!

Comment: @AlexanderLallier, nothing happens when i click the submit button.

Comment: Remove the second `submit` handler, and add `return false;` at the end of the previous handler

Comment: Have you hosted your php files on a some server or you are just trying ajax without hosting ?

Comment: @devutkarsh, I am just trying to play around with ajax on my localhost server.

Comment: @PraveenSinha it would be nice if you edited your question to describe the problem you are having, since looking in the comments is not ideal

Comment: @AlexanderLallier, I ll keep in mind next time. Thank you for the support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try by removing the second *submit()* function , modifying your first submit function to prevent default.

something like this.

```
$("#myForm").submit( function(event){
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var pick = $("#pick").val();
    var drop = $("#drop").val();
    var str = name+"/"+pick+"/"+drop;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "p_inp.php",
      data: "str="+str,
      success: function(data){
        $(".data").html(data);
      }
    });
  event.preventDefault();
});
```